# Frequent flats with Michelin Pro3's

Tags: tire, puncture

Since switching from the Michelin Pro2's to the new Pro3's I've experienced an increase in puncture flats.  Nothing has else has really changed in riding style or conditions.

The Pro3 ride much nicer.  A bit more supple.  But I'm tired of flatting.

Are these tires particularly prone to flats? Is there anything that can be done to prevent flats with them? If not, are there other similar tires that are more puncture-resistent?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles.SE. Please take a moment to read the FAQ, where it's explained that this site is designed for questions that have definite answers, not questions that generate forum-style discussions. (I haven't heard of any problems with these tires, BTW.) I've taken the liberty of making your question more answerable, but please change my edit if I've missed the mark.

Answer (score 3):

My answer to this was old school. I put on tire savers. This won't work with knobbies, but it will work great with street tires. Back in the day, I tried a bunch of things including puncture resistant and kevlar. I have both sew-ups and street tires and it stops the nagging flats from small things that don't puncture on the first pass.

[This](http://www.flickr.com/photos/10703870@N06/4683808689/in/set-72157622799024060/) will give you a picture of them.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles.SE. Interesting device! Have substituted a Flickr link for your eBay link, since auction links generally expire after a time.

Comment: Where can you buy a tire saver?  I can't find them anywhere...

Answer (score 2):

The reviewer in [this article](http://reviews.roadbikereview.com/michelin-pro3-race-review-pro-review) points out that expecting serious puncture resistance from performnce tires is unrealistic to say the least. However, the reviewer, a self-described heavier rider, had only one flat in 1000+ miles.

Several of the comments in [this review](http://www.bikeradar.com/gear/category/components/tyres/road/product/review-michelin-pro-3-race-tyre-31475/) say they've experienced punctures. However, I'm unable to find any durability comparisons with the Pro2.

Just for fun: Have you checked the tires before changing the tubes? Sometimes a thorn or a sharp piece of glass can be hard to find but still flat the same tube in the same place. A rough edge on your rim can also cause pinch flats if your tires are underinflated.

Durability and speed are not mutually exclusive properties, but there is a degree of tradeoff. If durability is important to you, I'd suggest looking into a set of touring tires. They'll slow you down a little bit, but you'll get more riding time in. (Unless you bike on some pretty bad roads indeed!)

Answer (score 2):

I might have found a reason for your issues.

I bought pair of Pro3 tires yesterday and I've installed them right away. After a short test ride, I noticed that small debris from the road stick to the surface of the tires. I've read some reviews about Pro3, and several mentioned this as well. This stickiness could affect tire durability for even casual riding because sharp pieces stuck in one place have time to work themselves into the tire.

Comment: This has been my experience too, everything sticks to these tires. I highly recommend an inspection everytime you get done with a ride, get anything out/off before it can get worked further into the rubber.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is similar, thus I am currently testing two other brands. I did move from the Michelins to Conti's Grand Prix 4000 S which have a fantastic feel and handle superbly, but did not last or hold as well to even the Michelin P3's, so I have moved on.

I currently have a set of Specialized Turbo PRO's on one bike and a Vredestein Fortezza TriComp on another. While it is too early too tell durability, I have not flatted on either set and the road feel and handling is adequate, but not up to par with Michelins or Conti's.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the Pro3s and I average a flat about every 100 miles.  They're not cheap either.  After I finish off my current supply of them, I'll be trying something a bit more puncture resistant...